# iOS, Core Data. Very slow with using of multithread

Tags: ios, multithreading, performance, core-data, datacontext

My code looks like something like this:

```
dispatch_async(background_save_queue, ^{

        NSManagedObjectContext *context = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] init];
        [context setMergePolicy:NSMergeByPropertyObjectTrumpMergePolicy];
        [context setPersistentStoreCoordinator:coordinator];
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:mainContext selector:@selector(mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification:) name:NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification object:context];


        //code to create objects with core data in context ("context" variable)

        [context save:nil];
        [context release];
}
```

And the similar code without multithread (with one context only) works much better.

Is my code wrong and are there are other examples of filling core data objects with multithreading?

Comment: I think it is the behavior of background thread.  It is not slower.  It is just not immediate.

Comment: What do you mean by "works much better"? In general it's a good practice to use the `initWithConcurrencyType:` initializer for the context with `NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType` and then dispatch chunks of works onto it using `performBlock:`.

Comment: I changed my code but I have the same problem. And it doesn't depend on outer code calls because it is too slow even without them.

Comment: Edited. Can you also give more info about using of performBlock:?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I checked that another thread is not slower than the main one. The problem is there are a lot of records in a data source and I need to perform a check for each record if this record already written in database. So the speed of my database creation process depends greatly on a count of the records and a database structure.

Comment: Apple shows in their guide for [efficiently importing data](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdImporting.html) how to implement such a find-or-create method efficiently. If you execute a fetch request for each record, it will be very slow. Each fetch request forces core data to go all the way back to disk.

Comment: Thanks I'll try it, but it doesn't solve my problem with duplicating of values? It means I get info from a defined source (text file) and it can give the same entity object multiple times with the same id. Currently I all the times search a db for a given id and do nothing if this record already exists.
As I understand the best solution of my problem is delete duplicates until they become entity objects.

Comment: The funniest thing is my main problem is even not duplicating data. I must save a non oriented graph into a database. So I have a big amount of vertices (almost 2k) and a lot of edges. I hope I can optimize this process.

Comment: In terms of duplication, you could just cache the ids you already imported and skip them on subsequent occurrences. I guess what you're describing with importing a lot of edges means that you have to resolve a lot of relationships. We recently wrote about a little trick to do this efficiently [in objc.io](http://www.objc.io/issue-4/importing-large-data-sets-into-core-data.html). Look for the last section "Importing Efficiently".

Comment: thanks for a link. I thought about using of dictionaries but I hadn't an example. I'll try it later